# Issue in Doctrine_Query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Below PHP/Doctrine query is not working properly

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create();
$q->from('EEvaluationround ER');
$q->leftJoin('ER.EEvaluationroundUser ERU');
$q->where('ER.job_id = ? and ER.active = 1 and (ERU.user_id = ? or ER.leader_user_id = ?)', array($this->job_id, $user->user_id, $user->user_id));
$res = $q->execute();
```

in **schema.yml** we have this

```
EEvaluationround:
  tableName: e_evaluationround
  columns:
    evaluationround_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    job_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    roundtype_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '10'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    leader_user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    autoadd:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    active:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: false
      default: '1'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    evaluationround_name:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Job:
      local: job_id
      foreign: job_id
EEvaluationroundUser:
  tableName: e_evaluationround_user
  columns:
    evaluationround_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    active:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: true
      primary: false
      default: '1'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    EEvaluationround:
      local: evaluationround_id
      foreign: evaluationround_id
```

Is there any issue with Left join syntax, it is throwing below error in log

[Thu Mar 25 07:37:31.544467 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 15834] [client 10.202.9.10:18298] Unknown record
property / related component "

```
\nalias : EEvaluationround\nforeign : evaluationround_id\nlocal :
evaluationround_id\nclass : EEvaluationround\ntype : 0\ntable : Object(EEvaluationroundTable)\nlocalTable
: Object(EEvaluationroundUserTable)\nname : \nrefTable : \nonDelete : \nonUpdate : \ndeferred :
\ndeferrable : \nconstraint : \nequal : \ncascade : Array\nowningSide : \nrefClassRelationAlias :
\nforeignKeyName : \norderBy : \n
```

" on "EEvaluationroundUser", referer:

[Thu Mar 25 07:37:31.544608 2021] [php7:error] [pid 15834] [client 10.202.9.10:18298] PHP Fatal error:
Cannot declare class Swift, because the name is already in use in
/home/project/code/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/vendor/swiftmailer/classes/Swift.php on line 18,
referer: